# How to upload file (txt) from java to restful webservice?

Tags: java, web-services

> I want to upload txt file from java application(software) to restful web-service , Because inside txt file i have list of sql query to execute. So , I want to upload file into web-service first then execute query line by line to database.

I converted txt file into List object then again into string and passed it but could not get success.

**Here is Webservice code**

```
package com.java.webservice;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

@Path("UploadFile")
public class UploadFile {

    private List<String> storedQueries = new ArrayList<String>();

    private Connection conn = null;
    // private PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    private Statement pstm = null;
    private ResultSet rs = null;
    private String q = "";

    // @GET here defines, this method will method will process HTTP GET
    // requests.
    @GET
    // @Path here defines method level path. Identifies the URI path that a
    // resource class method will serve requests for.
    @Path("/getTest")
    // @Produces here defines the media type(s) that the methods
    // of a resource class can produce.
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    // @PathParam injects the value of URI parameter that defined in @Path
    // expression, into the method.

    public Response getTest(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
        // String name = "Lokendra Pun ,Java Engineer";
        System.out.println("Your Name IS: " + name);

        java.util.StringTokenizer st = new java.util.StringTokenizer(name, ",");
        java.util.ArrayList newArrayList = new java.util.ArrayList();
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            // the trim() below may not always be desired or necessary
            newArrayList.add(st.nextToken().trim());
        }

        // this if statement only necessary because a String created from
        // ArrayList.toString() ends up as "[1, 2, 3, 4]" not, "1, 2, 3, 4"

        if (newArrayList.size() == 1) {
            // remove [] around item
            int length = ((String) newArrayList.get(0)).length();
            newArrayList.set(0, ((String) newArrayList.get(0)).substring(1, length - 1));
        } else if (newArrayList.size() > 1) {
            // remove '[' in first item and ']' in last
            int lastIndex = newArrayList.size() - 1;
            String oldString = (String) newArrayList.get(0);
            String newString = oldString.substring(1, oldString.length());

            newArrayList.set(0, newString);
            oldString = (String) newArrayList.get(lastIndex);

            newString = oldString.substring(0, oldString.length() - 1);
            newArrayList.set(newArrayList.size() - 1, newString);
        }

        System.out.println("newArrayList->" + newArrayList.toString());
        System.out.println("==================");
        for (int i = 0; i < newArrayList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Name" + i + " :" + newArrayList.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("==================");

        return Response.status(200).entity(name).build();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * method to get file name from remote server and process query into
     * database
     * 
     * 
     * 
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/getUploadQuery")
    public Response getUploadQuery(@QueryParam("file_name") String file_name,
            @QueryParam("database_name") String database_name) {
        System.out.println("I am inside getTeacher Method");
        String list = null;
        try {
            conn = getConnection(database_name);

            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file_name))) {
                        storedQueries.add(line);
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < storedQueries.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.println("Looping Query Length is: " + storedQueries.size());
                        System.out.println("Connection Object Inside Loop : " + conn);
                        pstm = conn.createStatement();
                        System.out.println("Looping Size now : " + i);
                        if (!storedQueries.get(i).equals("")) {
                            System.out.println("Query Before Executed is: " + storedQueries.get(i));
                            // pstm =
                            // conn.prepareStatement(storedQueries.get(i));
                            // pstm.executeUpdate();
                            pstm.addBatch(storedQueries.get(i));
                            pstm.executeBatch();
                        }

                    }

                    pstm.close();
                    conn.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                list = "true";
            } else {
                list = "false";
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Response.status(200).entity(list).build();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * method to connect to remote server database according to db and school
     * name
     * 
     * @param database_name
     * @return
     */
    public Connection getConnection(String database_name) {
        System.out.println("Database Name before Connection: " + database_name);
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Setup the connection with the DB
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + database_name + "?" + "user=root&password=java@android2016");
            System.out.println(conn);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return conn;
    }
}
```

**And here is code for service calling from java application**

```
package WSserviceCall;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class TestMain {

    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/MovieGalaxyService";
    public static final String PATH_TEST = "/UploadFile/getTest";
    public static final String PATH_LOAD_FILE = "/UploadFile/getUploadQuery";
    public static final String PATH_AGE = "/UploadFile/age/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            List<String> storedQueries = new ArrayList<String>();
            String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            String file_name = currentDirectory + "/databaseBackupScript.txt";

            String name = "Lokendra Pun Param";
            String age ="26";

            try{
               for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file_name))) {
                    storedQueries.add(line);
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           // String names = ""+aa;
            //System.out.println("Array Objec is: "+aa);
            //System.out.println("String Objects is: "+aa.toString());
            ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
            Client client = Client.create(config);
            WebResource resource = client.resource(BASE_URI);

            String param = storedQueries.toString();
            String temp_uri  = URLEncoder.encode(param, "UTF-8");
            WebResource testResource = resource.path(PATH_TEST).
                    queryParam("name",temp_uri);

            //WebResource testResource = resource.path(PATH_TEST);
            //      System.out.println("Client Response \n"
            //      + getClientResponse(testResource));
            //      System.out.println("Response \n" + getResponse(testResource) + "\n\n");
            String testValue = getResponse(testResource);
            System.out.println("Test Resource Value is : "+testValue);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
    * Returns client response.
    * e.g : 
    * GET http://localhost:8080/RESTfulWS/rest/UserInfoService/name/Pavithra 
    * returned a response status of 200 OK
    *
    * @param service
    * @return
    */
    private static String getClientResponse(WebResource resource) {
        return resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class).toString();
    }

    /**
    * Returns the response as JSON data
    * e.g : status : true or false
    * 
    * @param service
    * @return
    */
    private static String getResponse(WebResource resource) {
        return resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: `Because inside txt file i have list of sql query to execute` ... any hacker who is expert in SQL injection would be foaming at the mouth right now.  Is there any chance you could execute these queries from within your app layer, ideally using prepared statements?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tried line by line query execution from clinet to server but it seems slow and also unpredictable , how is it possible to send file from client (java desktop application) to server (with Restful service) ?